# How to count based on time logic & another column within a group in SQL

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have a table that contains the columns `accountID` `sub_account_ID` and `TimeStamp`. I want to write an SQL query that can tell me how many times an accountID switched to another sub_account_ID. This table logs actions that the accountID made, so not all rows in this table is a switching of sub_account_ID action. A switch happens only if the sub_account_ID changed in this table at a later timestamp.

| AccountID | Sub_Account_ID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1:00 |
| 1 | A | 2:00 |
| 1 | B | 3:00 |
| 1 | A | 4:00 |
| 1 | B | 5:00 |
| 1 | B | 6:00 |

The result I want in the end is to show that account_id 1 had 3 changes (sub_account switch between 2:00-3:00, 3:00-4:00, and 4:00-5:00).

I am thinking we need a `groupby` account_ID and some type of window function (maybe `lag`), but can't wrap my head around the logic needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `partition by AccountID` in case you will want to use this with more than one `AccountID` at a time.

```
select AccountID    
      ,Sub_Account_ID   
      ,concat(pre_time,'-',"Timestamp")                              as time_of_change
      ,sum(change) over(partition by AccountID order by "Timestamp") as running_sum_change
from   (
       select *
              ,case when lag(Sub_Account_ID) over(partition by AccountID order by "Timestamp") <> Sub_Account_ID then 1 end as change
              ,lag("Timestamp") over(order by "Timestamp") as pre_time
       from t
       ) t
where  change = 1
```

| AccountID | Sub_Account_ID | time_of_change | running_sum_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 2:00-3:00 | 1 |
| 1 | A | 3:00-4:00 | 2 |
| 1 | B | 4:00-5:00 | 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ph1qYoYl?hide=4)